# i want to display the data accordingly depending on the mouse hover on different buttons

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the data in json format.
By using ng repeat in angularjs , if particular button in navbar is hovered , it has to display the details of that.

Please help me.

Comment: And I want a Porsche. What have you tried ? What is your problem ? What is your question ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do something with ng-repeat you can assign action specific for an instance in repeat i.e.

#### html

```
<div ng-repeat="player in PlayerList">
  <!--do this -->
  <button ng-mouseover="DisplayThisPlayer($index)">Display</button>
  <!--or this -->
  <button ng-mouseover="DisplayThisPlayer(player)">Display</button>
  <!--or this -->
  <button ng-mouseover="DataToDisplay = player">Display</button>
</div>
```

#### js

```
$scope.DisplayThisPlayer = function ([index or player]) {
  $scope.DataToDisplay = $scope.PlayerList[$index]
  $scope.DataToDisplay = player
}
```